# Getting root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError while using Jersey ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey

```
INFO: Server startup in 6705 ms
Nov 29, 2013 6:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [JerseyServlet] in context with path [/jersey_project] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:649)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: this might help: http://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-uribuilder-uri/

Comment: tonyyan's solution posted on blog helps me. thanks

Comment: @DB5 Thanks, that worked!  Turns out the issue was not adding an "unrelated" dependency to uribuilder.

Comment: @DB5 You should have added this as an answer so that we can upvote it and would have better visibility.. BTW Thanks it saved my ass :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you're using Jersey 1.x (JAX-RS 1.1 implementation) with JAX-RS 2.0 APIs. In your application either switch to Jersey 2 (recommended) or replace JAX-RS 2.0 API jar with JAX-RS 1.1 API jar (it's already part of the `jersey-common` so removing 2.0 API should be sufficient).

Answer (score 6):

you have a maven dependency issue, delete all your dependencies in particular the conteiner jersey dependency and add this ones:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
<version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
<version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
<version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a more specific answer to the problem so I added the following plugin to maven:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce</id>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <dependencyConvergence/>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above showed me all the dependency conflicts so I managed to resolved more than the aforementioned problem and keep my dependency tree tidy.

The plugin runs when calling:

```
mvn clean install
```

And shows you a warning as follows:

```
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10 paths to dependency are:
+-com.omilia:partners:5.4.0-RC-3
  +-org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.27
    +-com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.10
      +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10
and
+-com.omilia:partners:5.4.0-RC-3
  +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6
    +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6
```

Subsequently, you can exclude the specific package, when referencing your dependency in your pom:

```
<exclusion>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

More Information can be found here:

[Dependency Convergence Maven Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html)